# How to implement bearer tokens with node.js + passport for authentication

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, passport-facebook, passport-twitter

I am trying to find some good documentation outlining how to use bearer tokens with passport.  I am using node.js as a rest layer and angularjs for the ui layer.  I am a newbie to node.js coming from a .net background.  I would like to provide the user with a mechanism for logging in with either a local strategy where they would provide a username and password or socially using their social credentials (facebook, twitter, etc.) if they would prefer.  From this point, I would like to generate a bearer token that would be returned to angularjs and used until it expires.  The examples I keep finding like https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer seems to indicate that the token would get passed to the BearerStrategy, which in turn would try to find the user in the database via the token instead of parsing the token as if it represented "the session".  If this is the case, and the bearer token changes everytime it expires, seems to be alot of updating to the person's user table.  Am I missing something here in the way I am understanding the url listed above?

Comment: i would suggest to not use passport for the route protection but express-jwt instead. I wrote a blog post about this topic that might help you: https://blog.hyphe.me/token-based-authentication-with-node/

Comment: Thank you, that appears to be what I am looking for.  Are there any issues with using this approach while also supporting facebook, twitter, etc.  Also, for facebook, twitter, examples are they getting the token from the external site and saving with the users account or would the token be different for the user at each login?

Comment: it def works with fb using passport-facebook-token package. Idk about twitter though, you would have to look into that.

Comment: Are the any special considerations I need to consider during the registration process to accommodate the jwt token or facebook scenarios?